# Editing Lightning Home Page narrow component Positions

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, home-page-component, lightning-home-page

I am finding it hard to get any documentation but can we make lightning home page to have the narrow component on left side rather than right side? So the wide component will be on right hand side. And Assistant component will be on left hand side

[image]

I want to use standard fucntionalities only. Thanks.!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is both **No** and **Yes**.

**No** - Because using the out of the box Home Page template, you cannot configure what you want. The standard out of the box home page template is as you see in the screenshot below. This necessarily means, the left panel components, viz., header and area below it cannot be switched with the right panel as you want.

[image]

**Yes** - You can create custom page templates and then use those in your application. With this approach, you can define the panels as you want and you will have full control on it. Any custom template created will be then available in the Lightning App Builder. You can find more on custom lightning page templates on the **[documentation here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_template_component.htm)**.